# Chat database model

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on implementing chat functionality in Spring-MVC. This is meant for private chat only. Now there is a situation where I have 2 users who are chatting. I would like to store their chats in the database. I am trying to think how can I save it so I can search for conversations between two users in a efficient manner.

Currently my idea is :

Each message has a messageid, messageTimeStamp, messageText and an identifier. Now this identifier is a String value of user1:user2. So when I want to load a conversation between two users, I have a logged in user1, so I can search in database where identifier user1 is present and load them as history.

Problem is loading individual chat history and overhead. Does this approach sound good, any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your idea is not that bad for start, but using an identifier column where you merge chat users in a string value 'user1:user2' is not really efficient. You will have to operate with strings later on and you cannot index the sender and the receiver of the message separately.
You could rather store the user id of the sender and the receiver in separate columns.

One other thing that you might consider is to have a separate 'conversation' or 'chat' table to store conversation relation data between users. Then, you refer to a conversation from the message table. So your tables might look like:

- conversation(id, user1, user2, time)
- message(id, sender, conversation_id, text, time)

One benefit is that, when you just want to operate with the conversations, e.g. count or get a list of active conversations between users, it will be more efficient this way.

You can find some more examples with a detailed explanation of such a design [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2013/05/message-conversation-database-design.html).

Comment: Turns out, I implemented what you said already. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: You are welcome, good to see that you ended up with the same solution.